# How to set a target option to a AJAX call in a html form submit fashion?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

In this project I'm working in I need to get some files from a repository. The files are supplied through a FileStream and the idea is to be able to download it right after the request is done. The server forces it to download via an application/octet-stream rule.

```
<form id="myForm1" action="http://fakepath/repository" target="iframe">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="bP0QjyW5Rmf5yZWNslO0jxNbPg2zXCNLGCTl4bIlhfqQsUxyJ2lFsVimEn1CDQYN">
    <button type="submit">DOWNLOAD</button>
</form>
<iframe frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

The above works pretty good for public files, but the problem starts when the private ones need to be downloaded - a token for authorization must be informed. 
AFAIK, I can't set headers on HTML form submit. An AJAX call would be ideal, since I can set custom headers on every request, but don't know if it is possible to set a target for the response, just like a form does. I know I can handle the response in the callback, but everything I'll have is the file's binary content being printed, not downloaded.

Being that said, I have the following questions:
- Using AJAX, is there a way to mimic this form behavior, that is, to set an automatic target to an Iframe at the response, forcing the file do download?
- Is there any other way to handle FileStreams on Javascript, where I can send Headers like this?

Comment: Ajax can not download the file.

Comment: If you have access to the server code your best bet is to modify the server to accept either header values or URL parameters or form values depending on what you are trying to achieve since changing headers and downloading a file isn't currently possible with HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('form').serialize();
```

That should give you everything that is in the form for AJAX. You would need jQuery for this.

Comment: Not what the OP is asking.